# Is type inference for arbitrary-rank types decidable when supplied type signatures?

Tags: type-theory, type-checking, type-inference, haskell

I found following statements in [6.4.16. Arbitrary-rank polymorphism](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/rank_polymorphism.html) of ghc document.

> GHC uses an algorithm proposed by Odersky and Laufer (“Putting type annotations to work”, POPL‘96) to get a decidable algorithm by requiring some help from the programmer. We do not yet have a formal specification of “some help”

I knew they don't formalize "some help" of Haskell's type system.
But in general, is type inference for arbitrary-rank types decidable when supplied type signatures? It probably be true, but are there any papers which prove this fact?

Comment: I don't think you mean to say System F here. Type inference for System F is trivial because the types are explicit; there is nothing to infer.

Comment: Yes. It was a mistake. I removed it.

Comment: What do you mean by "when supplied type signatures"? If all signatures are supplied then of course you don't need any inference.